# select elements depending on parameter passed through in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please find this http://jsfiddle.net/SPn3W/

I am getting some parameters through URL as in  http://mywed.com?state=NSW

I have a form where part of the html code is

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-4 col-sm-4 control-label" for="state">State:*</label>
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-8 stateDiv">
        <select class="form-control" id="state" name="state" mandatory="true">
            <option value="" selected="selected">-Please select-</option>
            <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
            <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
            <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
            <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
            <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to select the one that is coming frm the URL aka ... Since in this case we have NSW, NSW should change to selected. If parameter passed through was ACT, then ACT would be selected.

I have been trying as below

```
var vars = [], hash;
    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
}
if(vars['state'] != null){

}
```

How can I make it selected depending on the parameter coming through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone. All your answers helped me one way or another. This is what I ended up using

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   var vars = [], hash;
    var q = document.URL.split('?')[1];
    if(q != undefined){
        q = q.split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < q.length; i++){
            hash = q[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[1]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
}
    var urlState = vars['state'];
    if(urlState != null){
       $("#state").val(urlState);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To get right value of state you can use this function:

```
 function GetURLParameter(sParam)
    {
        var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++)
        {
            var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
            if (sParameterName[0] == sParam)
            {
                return sParameterName[1];
            }
        }
    }​

var state = GetURLParameter('state');
```

Try this if you are using jQuery 1.6 or higher:

```
$('#state option[value="'+ state +'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

For jQuery lower than 1.6 use this:

```
$('#state option[value="'+ state +'"]').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

View the example above, I assign the vars['state'] because we can't put ny vars into the url in jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/SPn3W/1/

Comment: sorry it is not getting selected. Basically the parameter passed through the URL needs to get selected in the drop down list so that user do not need to select it

Comment: yes in your vars['state'] did you get the right value? or the problem is to retrieve the value into the url also? Becauseif you have the right value with this script you can select it automaticalluy see the jsfiddle into my demo (I assign vars['state'] because into the url in jsfiddle we can't put anything) @Himu

Comment: I think it sould rather be `$('#state option[value="'+ vars['state'] +'"]').attr("selected", "selected")`

Answer (score 1):

```
       Try this  
        if(vars['state'] != null){
           $('#state').val(vars['state']);
        }


or you can change your code for getting query string

$.urlParam = function(name){
        var results = new RegExp('[\\?&]' + name + '=([^&#]*)').exec(window.location.href);
        if (!results)
        { 
            return 0; 
        }
        return results[1] || 0;
    }

if($.urlParam("state") != ''){
     $('#state').val($.urlParam("state"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just

```
$('#select').val(vars['state']);
```

should work. Just include this line inside document.onready()